# Drupal website having problems with SSL install

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

Hi I have a Drupal 6 website and for last two days tried to install SSL on it.

My problem is that some of the code in drupal especially for static images we use http so SSL complains.

I tried securepages module but it was of no help.

Do we have to check every code for reference if http and change it to // to make SSL run?

Please assist Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you call an image with http and you apply SSL/TLS on the domain, the domain is going to be "semi-secured" because some assets called over the SSL/TLS.

I know on WordPress that there are plugins for auto-fix the http calls and replace them with https, such images.

In general you need all the called and used assets to be called with SSL/TLS (https)

Comment: Hi thanks is there any module for drupal 6 that'll automatically replace http with https?

Comment: in case you are not aware of the following, I attach you a previous question on the same issue: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/169321/how-to-force-drupal-7-to-load-https-assets

Comment: also, i dont know about a spesific module mate. sorry. :/

Comment: Thanks it'd seem that In settings.php with: $base_url = 'https://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']; would it work with Drupal 6?

Comment: this is just a declaration of a PHP variable. It should work, but I don't know if it is going to fix your problem mate. Just tried it out and see the results.
Btw, you can debug the SSL/TSL from firefox (my opinion is better on firefox).

Comment: Also would this php setting change the 3rd party ad codes as well?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to discover what included files are causing this is to use the developer tools console in your browser.

In Chrome, press F12 and then the second tab from the left is 'console' you will see something like this

[image: mixed content warning]

Then you will need to go into your site and tediously track down the files page by page.  I am not sure if Drupal supports the vanilla protocol like wordpress does.  Instead of `http://example.com...` or `https://example.com...` you can simply use `//example.com...`